# Webscrape a site with authentication and Sign In with Google

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I need to scrape a site with authentication and I'm planning on using my google account to do so.

So far I've done:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://url.com/login"
r = requests.get(url)
```

When I tried to follow the Sign In with Google button, I realized that there's no href link within the HTML.

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to use selenium to automate signing in. Be aware that most site admins/developers will actively try to stop people from automating signing in to their site

Comment: share the website and consider that you can send the username and password via requests data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is a library that does http request directly through python, meaning that there's no browser involved. That implies that you can't scrape websites that require things like login in.

Give a look to [Selenium](https://selenium.dev/), a library that allows you to do request through your browser.